# OneSignal push notification sending to all user instead of one player

Tags: php, laravel, push-notification, onesignal

I am trying to send push notification to one device by its player_id stored in my database.
but whine it try it keep sending to all users
i don't know what is wrong in my code

```
  $fields = array(
            'app_id' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            'include_player_ids ' => $player_ids,
            'included_segments' => array(
                'All'
            ),
            'data' => $data,
            'headings' => $title,
            'contents' => $content,
            'web_buttons' => []
        );

        $fields = json_encode($fields);
        if($player_ids) {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
                'Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
            ));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

            $response = curl_exec($ch);

            curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove `'included_segments' => array('All'),`

If you fill both of `included_segments` and `include_player_ids`, you will send to all selected player ids and also all selected segments. Segment `All` mean all subscribers.

you can read about other option on [official documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference/create-notification)

Comment: it give me an error message ```{"errors":["You must include which players, segments, or tags you wish to send this notification to."]}```

Answer (score 0):

I need to remove `included_segments` and `web_buttons`
both of them not just `included_segments` , when I try to just remove `included_segments` it give me error of `{"errors":["You must include which players, segments, or tags you wish to send this notification to."]}`
also I don't need `'Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'`.